# What is the best way to iterate through a nested list of different numbers and make calculations?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I am trying to calculate the difference between 2 numbers within various lists within a nested list. The two numbers have the same indices for all of the lists.

I tried to do the following:

```
change = []
i = 0
for i in data:
    x = data[i][2] - data[i][3]
    change.append(x)
    i = i + 1
```

but it is giving me the TypeError "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list"

I understand why but I don't know how to change it to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming this is Python?

I don't see how `data` was created, but based on how it is used, I'm assuming it is a list of lists. The statement `for i in data` will actually iterate through each of the lists contained in `data`. No need to initialize `i` before or within the loop, it will be set to one of the lists contained in `data`.

This should do what you are intending:

```
change = []
for row in data:
    x = row[2] - row[3]
    change.append(x)
```

And even better with list comprehension:

```
change = [row[2] - row[3] for row in data]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I should have specified, it is python